# WMS authentication plugin

Tags: c#, authentication, plugins, wms

I'm trying to create a custom authentication plugin for WMS 2009 in C#.

I managed to implement something that for some reason blocks all requests...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("C0A0B38C-C4FE-43B5-BE9E-C100A83BBCEE")]
public class AuthenticationPlugin : IWMSBasicPlugin, IWMSAuthenticationPlugin, IWMSAuthenticationContext
    private const string SubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Media\\Server\\RegisteredPlugins\\Authentication\\{C0A0B38C-C4FE-43B5-BE9E-C100A83BBCEE}";

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey regHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
            regHKLM = regHKLM.CreateSubKey(SubKey);
            regHKLM.SetValue(null, "UC WMS Authentication plugin");

            RegistryKey regHKCR = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            regHKCR = regHKCR.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{C0A0B38C-C4FE-43B5-BE9E-C100A83BBCEE}\\Properties");
            regHKCR.SetValue("Name", CustomC WMS Authentication plugin");
            regHKCR.SetValue("Author", "Me");
            regHKCR.SetValue("CopyRight", "Copyright 2009. All rights reserved");
            regHKCR.SetValue("Description", "Enables custom WMS authentication");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message, "Inside RegisterFunction(). Cannot Register.");
        }
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction]
    public static void UnRegisterFunction(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey regHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
            regHKLM.DeleteSubKey(SubKey);

            RegistryKey regHKCR = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            regHKCR.DeleteSubKeyTree("CLSID\\{C0A0B38C-C4FE-43B5-BE9E-C100A83BBCEE}");
            regHKCR.DeleteSubKeyTree("CSEventTest.CSEventPlugin");
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message, "Cannot delete a subkey.");
        }
    }

    #region IWMSBasicPlugin Members

    public void InitializePlugin(IWMSContext serverContext, WMSNamedValues namedValues, IWMSClassObject classFactory)
    {
    }

    public void ShutdownPlugin()
    {
    }

    public void EnablePlugin(ref int flags, ref int heartbeatPeriod)
    {
    }

    public void DisablePlugin()
    {
    }

    public object GetCustomAdminInterface()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void OnHeartbeat()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region IWMSAuthenticationPlugin Members

    public IWMSAuthenticationContext CreateAuthenticationContext()
    {
        return (IWMSAuthenticationContext)this;
    }

    public int GetFlags()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(WMS_AUTHENTICATION_FLAGS.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public string GetPackageName()
    {
        return "Custom WMS Authentication";
    }

    public string GetProtocolName()
    {
        return "Basic";
    }

    #endregion

    #region IWMSAuthenticationContext Members

    public void Authenticate(object responseBlob, IWMSContext userContext, IWMSContext presentationContext, IWMSCommandContext commandContext, IWMSAuthenticationCallback callBack, object context)
    {
        callBack.OnAuthenticateComplete(WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, null, context);
    }

    public IWMSAuthenticationPlugin GetAuthenticationPlugin()
    {
        return (IWMSAuthenticationPlugin)this;
    }

    public string GetImpersonationAccountName()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public int GetImpersonationToken()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public string GetLogicalUserID()
    {
        return this.GetImpersonationAccountName();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Can anyone spot why this is happening?

Also, is there any way I could have a look at the code for the standard Anonymous Authentication plugin already installed on the server? Is it in an assembly somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  It isn't enough to return success status from the Authenticate method.

Your implemented method must retrieve a handle to a valid Windows Login.  Search the net for C# examples of how to call this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
bool result = LogonAPI.LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", LogonAPI.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LogonAPI.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref _userToken);
```

Store the IntPtr you get back from the LogonUser call and implement the GetImpersonationToken method like so:

```
public int GetImpersonationToken()
{
    return _userToken.ToInt32();
}
```

Somehow the plug-in is able to tie that integer value back to a real windows account.  I created a local account on the server that was in the Power Users group and used its username and password in the LogonUser method with the server being the domain.  Once it is able to do so, the media should stream.

My whole IWMSAuthenticationPlugin is as follows (it uses basic authentication):

```
public class AuthenticationContext : IWMSAuthenticationContext
{
#region IWMSAuthenticationContext Members

private WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT _result;

private readonly IWMSAuthenticationPlugin _plugin;
private Credentials _credentials;
private IntPtr _userToken;

public AuthenticationContext(IWMSAuthenticationPlugin plugin)
{
    _plugin = plugin;
}

public void Authenticate(object responseBlob, IWMSContext pUserCtx, IWMSContext pPresentationCtx, IWMSCommandContext pCommandContext, IWMSAuthenticationCallback pCallback, object context)
{
    // must be Unicode.  If it isn't, the 
    // challenge isn't sent correctly
    Encoding enc = Encoding.Unicode;
    byte[] response;
    byte[] challenge = enc.GetBytes("");

    try
    {
        response = (byte[])responseBlob;
        if (response.Length == 0)
        {
            // The client requested authentication; prepare the
            // challenge response to send to the client.  In order to 
            // do Basic authentication, be sure to return "Basic" from 
            // your implementation of IWMSAuthenticationPlugin.GetProtocolName()
            string challengeTxt = "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Domain\"";
            challenge = enc.GetBytes(challengeTxt);

            _result = WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_CONTINUE;
        }
        else
        {
            // parses Base64 encoded response and gets passed in credentials
            SetCredentials(enc.GetString(response));

            LdapConnection ldc = new LdapConnection("Domain");
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(_credentials.Username, _credentials.Password, "Domain");
            ldc.Credential = nc;
            ldc.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            ldc.Bind(nc); // user has authenticated at this point, as the credentials were used to login to the dc.

            // must log in with a local windows account and get a handle for the account.
            // even if success is returned, the plugin still needs a valid windows account
            // to stream the file.                    
            bool result = LogonAPI.LogonUser("local username", "local domain", "local password", LogonAPI.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LogonAPI.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref _userToken);
            _result = WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    catch (LdapException e)
    {
        _result = WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_DENIED;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _result = WMS_AUTHENTICATION_RESULT.WMS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
    }
    finally
    {
        pCallback.OnAuthenticateComplete(_result, challenge, context);
    }
}

public IWMSAuthenticationPlugin GetAuthenticationPlugin()
{
    return _plugin;
}

public string GetImpersonationAccountName()
{
    return "Domain\\" + _credentials.Username;
}

public int GetImpersonationToken()
{
    // somehow the plugin knows how this integer ties to a windows account.
    return _userToken.ToInt32();
}

public string GetLogicalUserID()
{
    return GetImpersonationAccountName();
}

public void SetCredentials(string responseStr)
{
    // for whatever reason, the responseStr has an extra character
    // tacked on the end that blows up the conversion.  When converting
    // from the Base64 string, remove that last character.
    string decoded = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(responseStr.Substring(0, responseStr.Length - 1)));

    // now that the string has been decoded and is now in the format
    // username:password, parse it further into a Username and Password 
    // struct.
    _credentials = new Credentials(decoded);
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the massive delay - seems about right although I haven't tried it (not working on that project anymore). Thanks.